# Как отловить emoji ID, aiogram

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

Вообщем у меня есть Telegram Premium, и я хочу получить ID премиум emoji (через бота). Я понимаю что нет прямого решения для aiogram, но кто разбирается подскажите пожалуйста как можно отловить emoji и получить його ID, а далее уже понятно через bot.send_message и т.д.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Никак. Даже если вы скопируете отправленное боту сообщение, премиум эмодзи превратятся в стандартные. Премиум можно только пересылать через forward_message, не более

Comment: Спасибо большое!